# How do I commit database table changes in Visual Studio 2012 Web Express?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

This is probably obvious, but I can't see it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Web Express.  I open an existing database table using the internal editor, go to table definition and add a couple of extra columns.

I can see the T-SQL for a create table, if I save the table I get a prompt to save a SQL file, if I run the SQL it's a create table...

How do I just alter the existing table?  Do I really have to do this manually?

Comment: The first scenario you are editing the data in the table, the second one you are talking about the structure of the table.  Do you want to edit the data in the table, or do you want to add new columns/changes columns of the table(i.e. the strucutre)?

Comment: @AaronLS Add columns, I opened the table definition.  I've corrected it, thanks!

Comment: ok, but the first scenario is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the top left there is going to be a button that says "Update". This will push the changes to your database. It will then create an alter script that you will run.

Answer (score 2):

{To overcome the issue in MS SQL Server 2012 - this cell has changed, the change has not been committed to the database}

Find the "**Change Type**" Drop-Down Menu towards the left side of the third row, in which you can locate the **Update** option, which will update the records in your table.

[image: checkout the screenshot].