# In Visual Studio, how to commit data to a database table without closing it?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, commit

I am filling database tables manually with a few items of test data before writing my ORM code. For two tables with a 1:N relationship, it would be convenient to first fill a row in the one table, then fill all related rows in the next table. For example, if I have a Magazine which consists of multiple Articles, I would enter a row in the Magazine table, enter all its articles in the Article table, and only then start with the next magazine.

The problem is that my auto-incrementing IDs are only created in the database on closing a table. So, after I fill the row in the Magazine table, I can guess its ID, but if I try to enter a row into Articles, I cannot use the guessed ID as a foreign key because the database notices that it doesn't exist yet. I have to close the Magazine table after each magazine before I can enter articles, then reopen it for the next magazine.

Is there an easier way to do it, possibly some kind of commit button which I cannot find?

Note that this is not the same question as [How do I commit database table changes in Visual Studio 2012 Web Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843481/how-do-i-commit-database-table-changes-in-visual-studio-2012-web-express). I am trying to save table data, not a table design.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I found this through Google because I was also looking for a commit button in Visual Studio (2013 for me).
After looking around a bit, I found that simply entering all data for the row and then pressing Enter will commit the row (row or some field in the row has to be selected).